Jsreport/ChromePDF headertemplate and footerTemplate position getting overflowed for multi page content
I'm using JsReport(with chrome-pdf) to generate pdf files from html. My html content has a table which is on the bigger side due to the data inside the table; hence the it's getting spread across 3 pdf pages where each of the pages content header and footer template. However, somehow, the main content is overflowing the header footer template. Here is the code:
{
"engine":"handlebars",
"recipe":"chrome-pdf",
"content":"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css\"><style>html,body{height:600;width:600;margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:80px;margin-right:20px;margin-bottom:20px}</style></head><body><div class='w3-container'> <h2>Displaying Blockquotes</h2> <p>The w3-panel class can be used to display blockquotes:</p><blockquote class='w3-panel w3-leftbar w3-light-grey'> <p class='w3-large'><i>'Make it as simple as possible, but not simpler.'</i></p> <p>{{name}}</p> </blockquote> </div><table id='datatable'><thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>City</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>User 1</td><td>50</td><td>City 1</td></tr> <!-- 100 more rows --></tbody></table></body></html>",
"helpers":"",
"chrome":{
   "format":"A4",
   "landscape":false,
   "displayHeaderFooter":true,
   "headerTemplate":"<style>body{font-size:16px;margin: 0;}</style><body>I am header</body>",
   "footerTemplate":"<style>body{font-size:16px;}</style><body>Page <span class=pageNumber></span> of <span class=totalPages></span></body>",
   "printBackground":true,
   "preferCssPageSize":true
},
"pdfOperations":[
   {
      "type":"prepend",
      "template":{
         "recipe":"chrome-pdf",
         "engine":"handlebars",
         "content":"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css\"><style>body{height:600;width:600;margin-top:80px;margin-bottom:80px;margin-right:20px;margin-bottom:20px}</style></head><body>I am first</body></html>",
         "helpers":"",
         "chrome":{
            "format":"A4",
            "landscape":false,
            "displayHeaderFooter":true,
            "headerTemplate":"<style>body{background-color: yellow;font-size:16px}</style><body>i m frontcover header</body>",
            "footerTemplate":"<style>body{background-color: green;font-size:16px}</style><body>i m frontcover footer</body>",
            "printBackground":true,
            "preferCssPageSize":true
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "type":"append",
      "template":{
         "recipe":"chrome-pdf",
         "engine":"handlebars",
         "content":"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css\"><style>body{height:600;width:600;margin-top:80px;margin-bottom:80px;margin-right:20px;margin-bottom:20px}</style></head><body>I am last</body></html>",
         "helpers":"",
         "chrome":{
            "format":"A4",
            "landscape":false,
            "displayHeaderFooter":true,
            "headerTemplate":"<style>body{background-color: yellow;font-size:16px}</style><body>i m backcover header</body>",
            "footerTemplate":"<style>body{background-color: green;font-size:16px}</style><body>i m backcover footer</body>",
            "printBackground":true,
            "preferCssPageSize":true
         }
      }
   }
]

}
Here is the issue with the header footer:

How to fix this

refer this link https://medium.com/@Idan_Co/the-ultimate-print-html-template-with-header-footer-568f415f6d2a. it's helpful to avoid the overflow

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
